# Added Auto Start of Kodi, Now I can't access my Regular user

Tags: autostart, kodi

I have followed the Kodi Wiki on how to auto start my media center, and it works perfectly! Only problem is is when I exit the system and try to enter my user Desktop, it gives me the error, "Failed to Start Session" Here is the Lightdm conf file that Kodi Wiki had me add...
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

```
[Seat:*]
autologin-user=kodi
autologin-session=kodi
```

Is there a way to configure this to have kodi auto start, but when I want to use my Desktop, be able to exit and log into Ubuntu 16.10?

**

## Happy New Year to ALL!

**

As requested by George....
[Kodi Wiki](http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Autostart_Kodi_for_Linux)

I did Step 1...

**1 Create a user to run Kodi**

For security reasons, it is recommended (but optional) to use a dedicated user to run Kodi. The user needs access to audio and video devices as well as access the internet if you're going to use any features that require internet access. Most methods present here allow to specify which user will start / own the Kodi process.

Notice the groups might vary from one distro to another. The groups used below are for Debian-based distributions. To create the user (named kodi here) and give it the necessary permissions, run

```
sudo adduser --disabled-password --disabled-login --gecos "" kodi
```

Then, assign it to the following groups in order to give it the permissions it needs.

```
sudo usermod -a -G cdrom,netdev,audio,video,plugdev,users,dialout,dip,input kodi
```

To give it access to the internet, add the group netdev as well.

and Step 6...

**6 Use autologin feature of lightdm**

This works if you have a window manager as well.

Install lightdm

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

Modify /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf and set the following settings under section 
[Seat:*]:

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

[Seat:*]
autologin-user=kodi
autologin-session=kodi
```

Reboot and you're done

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running ?

Comment: Please add the link to the steps you followed.

Comment: Unbuntu Version 16.10

Comment: What is the exact error or issue you see with the regular user.

Comment: It was "Failed to start session", it's fixed now that I re-installed Ubuntu session. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out what I did wrong as I traced my steps...

When I installed Xorg Legacy (As outlined in Step 5 of the Wiki), then realized that this step was not necessary, and purged and reinstalled Xorg, it removed my Ubuntu session. I had to re-install the missing files in my Ubuntu session, and the Unity greeter works perfectly now! This is the command I used.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-session
```

Thanks [George](https://askubuntu.com/users/459561/george) for making me re-trace my steps!

**The above Question is the exact steps to follow if your using a Desktop connected to a T.V. with a DVI to HDMI Cable as the Media Center for Kodi. When a member of my household wants to use Kodi, all the need to do is power on the computer and it boots straight to Kodi. I would like to stregthen my setup so that just any user cannot edit the Kodi Media Server settings, but that is a whole new topic. For now, this works great!**