# How do I stop kodi from autostarting?

Tags: 17.10, kodi

After installing kodi from their repos it automatically starts on boot and I can't access anything else but kodi. The way I fixed this is by booting ubuntu on xorg and then removing kodi. How do I make kodi behave more like in windows? Sorry if this is a noob question...

Comment: Does this https://askubuntu.com/questions/866644/added-auto-start-of-kodi-now-i-cant-access-my-regular-user help?

Comment: I switched to another distro, I never did solve this. Thanks anyway.