# Boot directly into Kodi

Tags: media

How could I make a media center with Kodi by directly booting into Kodi and hiding Ubuntu interface? 
I have no idea how to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Added Auto Start of Kodi, Now I can't access my Regular user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866644/added-auto-start-of-kodi-now-i-cant-access-my-regular-user)

Comment: Please see my answer, and remember to accept it if it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the login screen, select your username, then click on the cog wheel icon, and select `Kodi`, then enter your password.